# insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Hi I have a Postgres table named Light which has 4 columns as objects.
I am trying to write some sample data but getting error as below, referred similar question too, my syntax looks correct.

Can someone help me where i am missing  ?

```
INSERT INTO default$default."light" 
VALUES      ('sid', 
             '(1,2,3)', 
             'model123456', 
             (SELECT id 
              FROM   default$default."lightstate" 
              WHERE  id = 'cjy6y1iv500ag0721x7abj1um'), 
             'SouthZone', 
             (SELECT id 
              FROM   default$default."flashstate" 
              WHERE  id = 'cjy5u9li4006u0721ae6ul1ka'), 
             (SELECT id 
              FROM   default$default."lightgrpctrl" 
              WHERE  id = 'cjy5ugpy500 7r07213minpvqw'), 
             (SELECT id 
              FROM   default$default."powermeter" 
              WHERE  id = 'cjy5tcqkv004z07219knfw9z6'));
```

> **ERROR**:  insert or update on table "Light" violates foreign key constraint "Light_state_fkey"
>   **DETAIL**:  Key (state)=(cjy5u9li4006u0721ae6ul1ka) is not present in table "LightState".

Schema as below,

[image: Light Schema]
[image: LightState Schema]

Comment: Please add the definition of your tables `light` and `lightstate`. Given the error message, you attempt to write the id from `flashstate` into a column that is supposed to hold `lightstate` ids only which is checked by the constraint `light_state_fkey`.

Comment: thanks for responding , I have corrected  the grants for default schema and the syntax for postgres query required having the table name and column in quotes . with this correction i am able to insert data now .